# Отмена показа тех же самых картинок после нажатия на кнопку назад fancybox 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Использую в качестве фотогаллереи fancybox 3. Возникает следующая ситуация, когда я нажимаю на фотографию и начинаю листать галерею всё норм. Закрываю показ фоток, далее хочу вернуться на страницу назад и нажимаю на кнопку назад , то мне с опять показываются те же картинки. По идеи это стандартное поведение фотогаллереи. Вопрос как это отменить?

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    speed: 330,
    image: {
        protect: true
    }
});
<ul class="slides">
    <li class="slides__item" data-thumb="images/product/pic_smal.jpg" >
        <a class="slides__link" href="images/product/pic1.jpg" data-fancybox="images">
            <img class="slides__img" src="images/product/pic1.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="slides__item" data-thumb="images/product/pic2_smal.jpg" >
        <a class="slides__link" href="images/product/pic2.jpg" data-fancybox="images">
            <img class="slides__img" src="images/product/pic2.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="slides__item" data-thumb="images/product/pic3_smal.jpg" >
        <a class="slides__link" href="images/product/pic3.jpg" data-fancybox="images">
            <img class="slides__img" src="images/product/pic3.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: На мобильном используете?

Comment: на мобильном её нет - только декстоп

Comment: Странно зашел на сайт http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/ и моб версия есть и так в трех браузерах поклацал их пример нет такого поведения... как вы описываете.

Comment: на официальном сайте я тоже такого не обнаружил, но проблема всё таки есть(( Если залезть в исходный код на оф сайте, то можно заметить, что там другие чем у меня дата атрибуты используются